# Imperative of 'to lie'.

Tags: grammaticality, lie-lay-lain-laid

At our regular supermarket this morning I noticed that they have put stickers on the check-out conveyor which say 'Lay bottles this way' with an arrow indicating that they want them parallel with the belt.

I don't think one can form the imperative of 'lie' in that way. 'Laying' wine bottles sounds potentially painful on the abdominal muscles. I think they should say 'lie bottles this way'.

Does anyone agree?